# Python script analyzing log files

Tags: python, log-analysis

I am creating a python script to analyze a log file(example: http://www.monitorware.com/en/logsamples/apache.php) and needs suggestions of methods that I can use to achieve this.

1. reading the log file with `open` method. OK.
2. counting elapsed time of the log? Which method do I use to read from specific position within the log line? Example: `64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:05:49 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Double_bounce_sender?topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariables HTTP/1.1" 401 12846`
    How do I count elapsed time after a certain position like year in this case?

   I also need to display requests served per minute, total amount of data sent, average amount of data sent, largest amount of data sent in a single request.

Comment: Please show us the code you have already tried. Describe what works and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html) module to extract information from text (search, substr, etc.).

Then [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/time.html#time.strptime) could be your friend to convert those date-time values to datetime and do calculations on them.

After that I'd use [`numpy.ndarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) to store the data and generate further reports.

I also like [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/) and features  like `hist` to make some nice plots.